# Oracle 11g - How to speed up parallel insert with join on three tables

Tags: sql, performance, oracle, parallel-processing, oracle11g

we want to speed up the insert statement below. Right now it takes around 1+ hours to complete.

The PM table contains around 79M records, F1 has 4.8M records and the RESULT contains 80M records.

Any ideas how to speed this up?

```
insert /*+ PARALLEL(16) APPEND NOLOGGING */ into MATCH_DATE(ID1, ID2)
select /*+ PARALLEL(16) */ T1.ID ID1, T2.ID ID2
from PM T1, F1 T2, RESULT
where  RESULT.RECON_PM_ID = T1.ID
    and RESULT.STATUS in (:ZERO, :TWO)
    and RESULT.RECON_CONFIG_ID = :RECON_CONFIG_ID
    and T1.UPLOAD_DT >= sysdate - :ONE
    and RESULT.CREATE_DT >= sysdate - :SIXTY
    and RESULT.RECON_F1_ID is null
    and T2.STATUS = :ZERO
    and T2.UPLOAD_DT >= sysdate - :ONE
    and T1.TRAN_DT between T2.TRAN_DT - :ASDF
and T2.TRAN_DT + :ASDF
and T1.CHARGING_NO = T2.CHARGING_NO 
and T1.USAGE_TYPE = T2.USAGE_TYPE
```

Here is the execution statistics from Enterprise Manager:

[image: oracle parallel insert]

Comment: What indexes are on the PM table? Interesting that it does an INDEX UNIQUE SCAN of 78M then a TABLE ACCESS BY GLOBAL on the same table retrieving 82M - implies that it _may_ be worth creating an index on PM that covers all fields required.  In fact, worth posting the indexes on all tables involved.

Comment: This is extremely similar to your [last question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20047610/); the answer is almost identical. You're selecting almost 100% of all your tables but you're using nested loops and a few index scans.

As [jonearles suggested](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20055465/458741); update your statistics so you use hash joins (and hopefully full scan the tables) and use statement level as opposed to object level parallelism.

Answer (score 0):

Regular table statistics are of limited value when you have multiple predicates on the same tables, so make sure that optimiser dynamic sampling is being invoked. A regular explain plan will tell you, and by default I believe that 11g is going to invoke dynamic sampling on that query, but if not then the expected cardinalities are going to be inaccurate.

I'd avoid the use of bind variables for a query like that as well -- a variation in the values of the variables could mean that a completely different plan would be beneficial, and in the context of a multi-minute query the hard parse time will not be a significant issue.